# Symbol size in a ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to decide symbol size in a ggplot graph, however I get an error when trying ("Error in discrete_scale(aesthetic, "manual", pal, breaks = breaks, ...").

Does anyone has an idea why? Below is graph and data.

All help is much appreciated!

Cheers

```
df%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=days, y=mean))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=compound, color=compound, size=compound)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 17))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "grey48")) + 
  scale_size_manual(size=c("1.5","1.5"))
  labs(color = "Compound", shape = "Compound", size= "Compound") +
  labs(x = "days", y = "emission", title = "Emission") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(vars(soil_type), scales = "free_y")
```

Here is the data:

```
df <- structure(list(soil_type = c("mineral", "mineral", "mineral", 
"mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", 
"mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "mineral", 
"mineral", "mineral", "mineral", "organic", "organic", "organic", 
"organic", "organic", "organic", "organic", "organic", "organic", 
"organic", "organic", "organic", "organic", "organic", "organic", 
"organic", "organic", "organic"), compound = c("Acetaldehyde", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", 
"Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone", 
"Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetone", 
"Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone", 
"Acetone"), days = c(0, 4, 10, 17, 24, 66, 81, 94, 
116, 0, 4, 10, 17, 24, 66, 81, 94, 116, 0, 4, 10, 17, 24, 66, 
81, 94, 116, 0, 4, 10, 17, 24, 66, 81, 94, 116), mean = c(1.7, 
3.7, 2.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.8, 3, 2.2, 1.7, 1, 0.2, 0.1, 
0, 0, 4.9, 14.3, 8.8, 2.5, 0.7, 0, 0, 0.7, 0.6, 14.7, 22.1, 42.8, 
97.2, 29.6, 0.1, 8.1, 0.2, 0.1), se = c(0.4, 0.7, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 2, 5.7, 
4.5, 1.6, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.4, 6.6, 6.3, 28.2, 70.6, 25.3, 0.1, 
7.6, 0.1, 0.1)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), groups = structure(list(
    soil_type = c("mineral", "mineral", "organic", "organic"), 
    compound = c("Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone"
    ), .rows = structure(list(1:9, 10:18, 19:27, 28:36), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
df%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=days, y=mean))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=compound, color=compound, size = compound)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 17))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "grey48")) + 
  scale_size_manual(values=c(1.5,1.5)) + 
#  labs(color = "Compound", shape = "Compound", size= "Compound") +
  labs(x = "days", y = "emission", title = "Emission") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(vars(soil_type), scales = "free_y")
```